# versioning conflict in gradle

Tags: android, build.gradle

I have got an error "Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}"

I would like to seek your advice that what could I do with this problem.

Thank you for your help.

```
My gradle in app level

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gtlab.asap"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'){ exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'}
}
```

My gradle in project level

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude support library from espresso-Core as follows:

```
 androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:3.0.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
 }
```

You also need to ensure that your `appcompat` and `design` library have same latest version as follows:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

Comment: I would like to ask what's these two lines (androidTestImplementation) for as these lines are generated automatically when this project is created. Thanks!

Comment: @George espresso-core has some internal dependency on support library which could leak in your dependency during gradle build. Adding this lines ensure that they are excluded.

Comment: @George After adding this line, is it working for you?

Comment: just tried it and it doesn't work. Same error has displayed.

Comment: @George can you remove `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` since you are already declaring specific library?

Comment: but i got another issue that "Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior ".... i guess it's also related to the versioning conflicts?

Comment: @George No I think its another issue. Clean and Rebuild first. If that doesn't help, then Update your question with updated build.gradle

Comment: i tried clean and rebuild but the problem still exists. I have updated my gradle content for your reference. Thanks

Comment: @George can you downgrade appcompat to `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'`

Comment: It works after downgrade to 26.1.0, it seems that I need to randomly try different version in order not to crash the version of other library... is there any good way to manage it ?

Comment: @George for me this combination works: `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'` &
    `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'` &
    `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'`

Comment: @George great! remember to approve the answer, so that others can benefit too

Comment: Have u checked this [post](https://medium.com/@suchydan/how-to-solve-google-play-services-version-collision-in-gradle-dependencies-ef086ae5c75f)